# How to use custom css file for layout of a module in Yii2

Tags: php, css, layout, module, yii2

I am using basic pack of Yii2. I created a module named Admin and I want this module has its own layout. But I don't know where to put all its CSS files. Then, how to include them in layout.php.

My directory structure:

```
basic
-- module
  -- admin
    -- controllers
       -- DefaultController.php
    -- views
       -- default
       -- layouts
          -- main.php
          -- css
             -- style.css
```

In main.php, I use this code, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php $this->registerLinkTag([
    'rel'  => 'stylesheet',
    'href' => 'css/style.css',
]);
$this->head(); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create custom asset bundle class file here:

```
frontend/module/admin/assets/AdminAsset.php
```

It is important to initialize [`$sourcePath`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$sourcePath-detail) and [`$css`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$css-detail) variables properly. Here is an example:

```
use yii\web\AssetBundle;   

class AdminAsset extends AssetBundle {

    // The directory that contains the source asset files for this asset bundle
    public $sourcePath = '@app/module/admin/web';

    // List of CSS files that this bundle contains
    public $css = ['css/admin.css'];

}
```

Now you can register this AdminAsset bundle (in layout, view, etc.):

```
use frontend\module\admin\assets\AdminAsset;
AdminAsset::register($this);
```

Comment: not able to register Admin. It shows me unable to find class Admin

Comment: Remove `public $basePath = '@webroot';` and `public $baseUrl = '@web';` if u use `public $sourcePath`

Answer (score -1):

Open the 'basic' folder. you will see a folder named assets.
Then open the assets folder and in the AppAsset.php file add your css

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/main.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: This will add these css files to the whole project, right ? How can i add to just 1 module ?

Comment: So, you can just comment the bootstrap part i.e. public $depends = [
       // 'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        //'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ]; It will automatically select the file you need